# UWP Creation of app packages loses localizations

Tags: c#, localization, uwp, globalization

I have bunch of languages:

[image]

I'm creating packages for Hockey App distribution.

[image]

Selected `Never`, in order to include all resources.

Installing the app on my PC, if I have this settings:

[image]

No Latvian in settings, then the app will not switch to LV language - it will use EN.

But why, when I have set the "Generate app bundle" to `Never` as described here:

http://www.guruumeditation.net/en/dynamically-change-the-language-of-a-universal-app/

**What I want: I want a simple app, that has a menu with many languages (not based on users OS settings) and user could switch the language in runtime without app restart.**

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. This link helps to achieve a normal behavior:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn482043.aspx

Shortly:

1) Modify the .csproj
2) Create app bundle = always ( to include packages for x86, x64 and ARM )

And thats it. The language resources will always be available in app